# Json to CSV, with dynamic and complex json

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am converting a very complex JSON (would be dynamic) to csv. Each record won't be as similar to other records as being shown. Any attribute which is null will not be included in the record (as per predefined JSON format).

Also it is possible for me to find out the total number of attributes that can come in the file, so if it helps to create a header file (output csv file) and then map the values from JSON record?

Below is the sample of my JSON with two records (could have more than 10K records during run time):
Please help or share code  if some one has already solved similar challenge :

```
[
    {
        "RecordId": 1,
        "attributes": {
            "ActiveFlag": [
                {"value": "Y", "mandatory": "No"}
            ],
            "Address": [
                {
                    "AdressLine1": [
                        {"value": "QWERT", "mandatory":"No"}
                    ],
                    "Zip": [
                        {"value": "12345", "mandatory":"No"}
                    ],
                    "State": [
                        {"value": "FL", "mandatory": "Yes"}
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "CountryCode": [
                {"value": "France", "mandatory": "Yes"}
            ],
            "LastName": [
                {"value": "Brown", "mandatory": "No"}
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "RecordId": 2,
        "attributes": {
            "ActiveFlag": [
                {"value": "Y", "mandatory": "No"}
            ],
            "Address": [
                {
                    "AdressLine1": [
                        {"value": "ABCD", "mandatory": "No"}
                    ],
                    "Zip": [
                        {"value":"2345", "mandatory":"No"}
                    ],
                    "State": [
                        {"value": "IN", "mandatory": "Yes"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "AdressLine1": [
                        {"value": "LMNDS", "mandatory": "No"}
                    ],
                    "Zip": [
                        {"value": "1234567", "mandatory": "No"}
                    ],
                    "State": [
                        {"value": "ZX", "mandatory": "Yes"}
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "CountryCode": [
                {"value": "France", "mandatory": "Yes"}
            ],
            "FirstName": [
                {"value": "Dan", "mandatory": "No"}
            ],
            "Education": [
                {
                    "College": [
                        {
                            "Name": [
                                {"value": "CityCollege", "mandatory": "No"}
                            ],
                            "ContactNumber": [
                                {"value": "9876543210", "mandatory": "Yes"}
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

This is what I am trying, but not helpfull

```
def json_to_csv(newFile):
    myFile=open('data.json', 'r')
    myObject=myFile.read()
    myFile.close()
    myData=json.loads(myObject)

    #print(myData)
    myFrame=pd.DataFrame(myData)
    myFrame.to_csv("raw_data.csv", index=False)


    df_file=pd.read_csv("raw_data.csv")
    print("Raw Data summary")
    print(df_file.describe())
    df_null_val=df_file.isnull().sum()
    df_file_columns=list(df_file.columns.values)
    df_null_columns=df_null_val[df_null_val!=0]
    df_null_columns.index[0]

mean_null_columns=[]
for obj in df_file_columns:
    for i in range(len(df_null_columns.index)):
        if (obj==df_null_columns.index[i]):
            mean_null_columns.append(int(df_file[obj].mean()))


for i in range(len(mean_null_columns)):
    print("%s \t has mean value \t %s" %(df_null_columns.index[i], mean_null_columns[i]))


for j in range(len(df_null_columns.index)):
        df_file[df_null_columns.index[j]]=df_file[df_null_columns.index[j]].fillna(mean_null_columns[j])


print("Summary for the cleaned data after filling up the missing values with mean \n")
print(df_file.describe())


df_file.to_csv("clean_data.csv", index=False)
```

Need out put as below :

```
RecordId    attributes_ActiveFlag_value attributes_CountryCode_value    attributes_Lastname_value   attributes_Address_AdressLine1_value    attributes_Address_Zip_value    attributes_Address_State_value  attributes_FirstName_value  attributes_Education_College_Name_value attributes_Education_College_ContactNumber_value

1   Y   France  Brown   QWERT   12345   FL
2   Y   France      ABCD    2345    IN  Dan CityCollege 9876543210
2   Y   France      LMNDS   1234567 ZX  Dan CityCollege 9876543210
```

Comment: Do you not have any knowledge of the JSON that you are loading? It's possible to only set headers after the entire thing has been read but is likely to use a lot of memory

Comment: structure of the json is known, however problem is with keys which could possibly be omitted if they are null in any of the record. In such scenario,I want to assign null value in the CSV target file.
As I know the all columns that can come in json files in total, so I can just map keys and values to my csv(in the example, like I dont have college information for the first record so it has to kept null in the csv file)